# Pentaho PRD - Summing Group'ed Values w/o Using SQL (Object-Based Datasource)

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

In Pentaho's PRD, I am working with an object datasource (i.e. I do not have a SQL query I may edit to group the data).  To realize the required report, I must group the data within the PRD (OK) and only show these grouped values (OK).  How can I sum the group values in the group headers to generate totals (MY PROBLEM) when there are multiple records per group?  Here is a simplified example:

```
Assume the dataset I provide to the PRD is:
X   42    1
X   42    2
X   42    3
Y   10   12
Y   10    7
Z    8   22
Z    8   92

So, I need to display groups based upon column 1 and 2 only.
Column 3 is excluded; but, I can't remove it from the dataset.
Then, I must provide a total for the 2nd column, as follows:
X      42
Y      10
Z       8
---------
Total  60
```